# MVC Pattern with multiple objects

Tags: java, model-view-controller, arraylist

In an example I got at school of the MVC pattern we had 3 classes `Student`, `StudentView` and `StudentController`. The controller has an instance of the model (`Student`in this case) and an instance of the controller. The problem i have with this is that the controller only handles a single object.

You obviously can have more students so I have an `ArrayList<Student>` somewhere. where do I put it? and how do I handle the model and view then?

My initial thought was to put the list in `StudentController` but then I found out that the controller is no longer for a single instance of `Student` but for the list so do i need to make 2 seperate controllers? one for `Student` and one for the `ArrayList<Student>` called something like `AllStudents`?

Edit: The application is a simple grading system for students. Students follow Coursrs the and a Course can have a Grade. the View displays the data of the student, course or grade in the console. The data is hard coded in the programme (objects are made 'on-the-fly').

Comment: That's when you create a persistence layer. Typically this layer provides an interface through *repositories*. Wisdom you will find, when into repositories you look.

Comment: You save all instances of the Student in the model.

Comment: You save the student models in a class StudentList or StudentData or StudentDB.

Comment: So the MVC part stays the same, only I add a persistence layer, get the 'model' via the persistence classes and put them in the controller?

Comment: The persistence is part of the model. The "model" in MVC does not refer to just a single "model" (as in: "type") but rather the entire body of the codebase. Frankly this question is way too broad to answer and doesn't belong here on SO anyway. The best thing you could do is start reading blogposts on the MVC architecture and repository design pattern. Look at example implementations.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I guess your'e right, thanks anyway for trying to help me. Found a very similar question on meta [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134820/in-an-mvc-system-where-should-the-database-persistence-code-sit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model is not necessarily just one class, it's a layer. Your Student Class as **a Domain Object** in your model layer now you need a Service and maybe some kind of a persistence/orm in your Model. A Service could be StudentService with methods like getAllStudents() returning a List. The StudentService may have an instance of a Connector to get the Data from a Database or a File.

Comment: or in this case `StudentService` has an `ArrayList<Student>`. but how does the MVC part work then? The controller still only controlls 1 domain object then?

Answer (score 0):

That is a question leading to the much broader question of: what does the rest of the application do?

It is obviously totally fine to have a 1:1:1 relation between view, controller an model. wht you might be interested in is an event bus. When the model of interest changes, the controller gets notified and updated with a new Student reference.

Or the controller gets the whole list and the view sends an event to the controller indicating that a different instance from the collection should be displayed.

In many application you'll have a master and detail views. The master view displays a list of all students. When one student is selected to be displayed in the detail view, a notification/an event is dispatched. This is basically a publish/subscribe observer/subject model. The detail view controller will be notified and display the proper data accordingly.

Comment: Added some context so it's more clear what the applications needs to do.